# How do I override part of the main loop in my child theme?

Tags: loop, customization

I have a child theme based on the twenty ten theme which I am happy with except for one thing.  My gallery posts (I am a photographer so the goal of my blog is pictures) do not show any images from the post on the main page.  I want to have my main page be a list of recent gallery posts each of which should show the shortened version of the description with a preview image (first image from the posted gallery).  I am using NextGen Gallery and slim box to display my images - if that makes a difference.

I have found the place where the main loop creates the entry for each post on the main page:

```
    <?php if ( is_archive() || is_search() ) : // Only display excerpts for archives and search. ?>
        <div class="entry-summary">
            <?php the_excerpt(); ?>
        </div><!-- .entry-summary -->
<?php else : ?>
        <div class="entry-content">
            <?php the_content( __( 'Continue reading <span class="meta-nav">&rarr;</span>', 'twentyten' ) ); ?>
            <?php wp_link_pages( array( 'before' => '<div class="page-link">' . __( 'Pages:', 'twentyten' ), 'after' => '</div>' ) ); ?>
        </div><!-- .entry-content -->
<?php endif; ?>
```

So, what I need to do is one of the following:

1. Override `the_content` method to include my gallery's preview image along with what the theme does already.
2. Override part of the main loop above to add an image after the call to `the_content` and before the call to `wp_link_pages`.
3. Override the whole main loop to do the same.

I feel like I am missing something obvious because I see serious down sides to all three options I can come up with:

1. I do not see any reference to overriding functions like `the_content` and even if I could I want to add to it not replace it.  Is there even away to call the original method's functionality after you override a method?
2. As far as I can see there is no way to override part of a loop - its all or nothing.
3. Which leads me to 3 - replacing the main loop.  At that point I have to seriously wonder if it is worth having a child theme if I replace the main loop.  That's a lot of code that I don't need to own that I would end up owning.

Is there an obvious way to do this that I am missing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of overriding the main loop, you can always just create a template, similar to the main loop and use that on a separate page (which you then set to display as your home page).

You'd just need to set up a wp_query in that template to call the posts you want and run a loop on that.

That way everything is left in tact and you just have one page in your child theme. Then you can add what you like after the_content();.

That's how I'd normally go about this sort of thing.

See here: http://codex.wordpress.org/Stepping_Into_Templates

Comment: Brilliant!  I was hoping there would be a better way.  So, in the twenty_ten theme the index.php file has this comment above the call the main page loop `<?php
   /* Run the loop to output the posts.
    * If you want to overload this in a child theme then include a file
    * called loop-index.php and that will be used instead.
    */`.  So, I still have to repeat the contents of the loop.php file but I can have my own that resides next to the original.  Seems like a good way to go.

Comment: Yeh, but you can still leave the main loop intact if you don't want to override it. Then just set up a template with loop for pulling portfolio posts only, and use this on a 'Home' page. That way if you want to use the main loop later (for a more complete blog, not just porfolio), it's still there. edits: grammar.

Answer (score 0):

Something to consider ...

Twenty Ten supports the Gallery post-format, you can simply create a "loop-gallery.php" template to be used with the theme rather than having to specifically over-write the "index" and/or create a Child-Theme.

NB: If the Twenty Ten authors choose to add a 'loop-gallery' template then you will need to over-load it via a Child-Theme.

Comment: I don't want to mess with the look of the gallery pages them selves.  I am happy with the way they work now - using the NextGen plugin and slim box.  All I want to do is make my home page better by having an image thumbnail for each gallery post appear on the home page. A loop-gallery.php would replace my gallery page generation and not the main page generation - correct?

Comment: You are correct ... I misread the point of you wanting to modify your "main page".